# Screen content overlapping Navigation drawer in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, navigationbar, kivymd

[image]

As you can see any content from my screen is overlapping on my navigation bar
My screen and nav bar code

```
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "My App"
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                        
                        right_action_items: [["login",lambda x: app.login()]]
                        elevation: 10
                    Widget:
                    MDBottomAppBar:
                        MDToolbar:
                            left_action_items: [["white-balance-sunny",lambda x: app.dark()]]
                            mode: 'end'    
                            type: 'bottom'
                            icon: 'plus'
                            on_action_button: app.new()
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: '8dp'
                padding: '8dp'
                Image:
                    source: 'no_pfp.jpg'
                MDLabel:
                    text: '         Naitik'
                    font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                MDLabel:
                    text: '            contact@foxex.xyz'
                    font_style: 'Caption'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Profile'
                            IconLeftWidget: 
                                icon: 'face-profile'
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Login'
                            IconLeftWidget: 
                                icon: 'login'
```

I tried to put MDNavigationDrawer and it's stuff above screenmanager but then it become transperant
What can i do?

Comment: Not possible to find the problem without seeing the actual `root` structure of your app.

Comment: @ApuCoder https://collabedit.com/harq8

Comment: Try posting the code (in the link) here for everyone's convenience and easy access.